# the regular expression works in Java, but not in Javascript

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like

```
f[u\W&&[^\s,]][c\W&&[^\s,]]?k(?!(uoka|uyama|ushima|nowledge))
```

to find some f words, but it works in Java, but it cannot find the f words in Javascript, what's the difference for this expression in Java and javascript? and how to solve it, anyone can give me an idea, thanks.

I tried to change "]]" to "]", seems it works in Javascript, but I don't know why, the bracket is not paired in this way

Comment: You need to provide examples of the data you're working with and expected results

Comment: There is no `&&` class intersection operator in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not support the [class intersection operator `&&`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#intersection).

So in particular, JavaScript does not deal with `&&` in that way when it parses `[u\W&&[^\s,]]`. Java interprets this as:

*Match a character that is either `u` or a non-alphanumerical character, but not a white-space or a comma.*

You can convert this by using a negative look ahead for the "but not..." part: `(?![\s,])[u\W]`. The same workaround will work for `[c\W&&[^\s,]]`.

So that leads to this regex:

```
f(?![\s,])[u\W](?![\s,])[c\W]?k(?!(uoka|uyama|ushima|nowledge))
```